# PostgreSQL Primary and Foreign Key

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

Next question to you guys.

I Have two tables STUFF and THINGS. First one with two column: ID and CHECKED.
ID is primary key for this table. it looks like this:

```
ID CHECKED
1 Y
2 N
3 Y   
.....
```

Second Table, named THINGS, has also a few column but what is important, in last column there should be ID of last thing i put into STUFF ID column

Now, I put:

> INSERT INTO STUFF(CHECKED) VALUES 'Y' RETURNING ID

-it will return ID=4

And here is the problem, after that I want to put something to THINGS table which is created like this:

> CREATE TABLE THINGS(XXX Varchar(), YYY varchar(), ID2 SERIAL REFERENCES STUFF(ID))

so when i put anything to THINGS:

> INSERT INTO TABLE THINGS(XXX, YYY) VALUES('xxx','yyy')

And I want to have in ID2 this number which was the last ID I put into STUFF, because now there is first free number from there :/

Answer (score 0):

Your column ID2 should be integer, not serial.

A serial column increments automatically with every insert. There is no way to make sure ID2 will always have the same value as the ID of your primary table.

The right way to do this is capture the ID returned by the insert into your primary table and do something like INSERT INTO child_table (f1, f2, id2) values('foo', 'bar', captured_id);